# regular expression to get string from text()

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, scrapy

I have this html:

```
<p class="marB0">Phone:+97143396222<br>
                    Email:spf476@spfrealty.com</p>
```

And I want to get the phone number

I get the text like this:

```
normalize-space(.//div[@class='authorinfo left'][2]/p[@class='marB0']/text())
```

and the result is:

```
u'Phone:+97143396222 Email:spf476@spfrealt'
```

I tried this regular expression:

```
Phone:\s*(\d+\.\d+)(Email:)
```

but I got empty result

Comment: Where's the code? It might be returning an empty set depending on the code as well.

Comment: @BK201 I gave you the code, it just `normalize-space(.//div[@class='authorinfo left'][2]/p[@class='marB0']/text())` and I showed you the results which are `u'Phone:+97143396222 Email:spf476@spfrealt'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern isn't catching the `+` or the email:

```
In [19]: re.match("Phone:\s*\+?(\d+)\s*Email:\s*(.+)\s*",'Phone:+97143396222 Email:spf476@spfrealt').groups()
Out[19]: ('97143396222', 'spf476@spfrealt')
```

Comment: the `match` function does't exist

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: What? Why are you commenting on OP's usage? Don't tell me you're one and the same?

Comment: Just use `"Phone:\s*\+?(\d+)\s*Email:\s*(.+)\s*"` as the regex pattern then.

Comment: @BK201 we are working together on the same code now.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the phone number, this pattern should work:

```
"Phone:\s*\+?(\d+)"
```

Use it like so:

```
import re

pattern = "Phone:\s*\+?(\d+)"
text = "Phone:+97143396222 Email:spf476@spfrealt"
res = re.match(pattern, text).group(1)
print res
```

Result:

```
97143396222
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Let us know if this helps.

### **EDIT:**

Not so versed in Scrapy, but I think this should more or less hit the mark:

```
xxx.select("normalize-space(.//div[@class='authorinfo left'][2]/p[@class='marB0']/text())").re("\s*\+?(\d+)")
```

Warning, however, as based on [this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.7/topics/selectors.html), it seems like doing it this way also returns an array.

Kindly test it and hit me back of the results.

Comment: My situation is scrapy, so I must use this `sel.xpath().re()`, I used that in cmd. and I have to make all the statments in one statement

Comment: The code in the previous answer works, but I can't use it because it gives me an array but I just need the phone. Alo, I can't take the first element of that array becuase as Itold you, i need to make just one statement

Comment: Hm. Not so versed in Scrapy, but I'll give it a shot. :)

Comment: Check the edit above. Note that the above also captures the `+` symbol. Modify as necessary to remove it.